# Is it possible assign the checked state to the value of the current checkbox in razor form without onclick method?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, checkbox, razor-pages

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC Web Application project.
I want to send the checkbox's checked state as the value to the model's related parameter on form submit.
I have seen so many examples that using jquery to get/set the value of the checkbox via onchange methods.

**What I wonder is that is it possible to assign the current checkbox's checked state to the value in a similar way to the code below.(it doesn't work)**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="IsActive" name="DTO.IsActive" checked="@Model.IsActive" value="(this.checked)"
```

One of the simplest working examples I found is the following but it returns false if the checkbox is checked by default and its state is not changed.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="IsActive" name="DTO.IsActive" checked="@Model.IsActive" onchange="if(this.checked) this.value='true'; else this.value='false';" >
```

I know that there are many ways to achieve what I want but I want the cleanest solution.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The structure of my code is as follows:

View

```
@model MyModel
<form id="UpdateForm" class="was-validated" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="Update">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="DTO.Name" value="@Model.Name" required>
            <input type="checkbox" id="IsActive" name="DTO.IsActive" checked="@Model.IsActive">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(Guid id, UpdateDto DTO)
{
...
}
```

**Solution**
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes

In View

```
<input type="checkbox" " id="IsActive" name="DTO.IsActive" checked="@Model.IsActive" value="true">
```

In DTO Object Set Default

```
public bool IsActive { get; set; } = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using an inline razor statement @()
It would look something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="IsActive" name="DTO.IsActive" @(Model.IsActive ? "checked" : "") />
```

also you could use the Checkbox helper

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive )
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, this piece of code @(Model.IsActive ? "checked" : "") states that if the IsActive parameter from the model is true then the checbox will be shown as checked and not checked if otherwise, am I correct? However that only helps me assign the value when I GET the model from the controller, it doesn't help me assign a value to the model I will send to controller on form submit. The user may change the checked property in between. Could you please elaborate if I'm mistaken?

Comment: Hi, yes but no: the first option allows you to show the checkbox as checked. To send the value back to the controller, the name attribute must match the name of the property of the model (eg `name="IsActive"`). The second option however helps you with both (load and send the data). Something you need to be aware is that a checkbox with value="foo" will get to the controller like "foo" if the checkbox is checked but if its not checked it wont get to the controller (yes, its confusing) so i recommend you to use a default value for the empty checkbox.

Comment: Hey Daniel, can you guide me on how to implement the second approach on the structure I modified in the question please? How can I use @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive ), to bind the checkbox cheked state value to outgoing DTO? Normally I use attribute name convention to bind the data with name="DTO.Attribute" so what is written in the textbox is binded to the DTO.Attribute. How can I implement a such structure in @Html.CheckBoxFor() ?

Comment: Well you can use your current approach having a propery called IsActive in your model with a default value of false and the input with a value="True". If you want to use the @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive ), then this will generate the necesary HTML for the model to get back to the controller. Take a look at this for example, it will give you an idea https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes

Comment: Even though I didn't love having to create 2 input fields for a single checkbox, it is what I was looking for! Thanks Daniel :)

In the end I'm using as following

<input type="checkbox" data-val="true" " id="IsActive" name="DTO.IsActive" checked="@Model.IsActive" value="true">
<input name="DTO.IsActive" type="hidden" value="false">

Comment: Im glad it works for you! however just a little advice: using HTML helpers maintains your code shorter, more readable and helps with validations, so check them out and think about using them in the future ;)

Comment: PS: I did not suggest using two inputs for a single field, I dont recommend that. I recommend better using a default value. For example: your controller could be something like `public ActionResult SaveForm(bool isChecked = false)` and then your check  <input type="checkbox" value="True" name="isChecked " /> so then in your controller you will have true if checked and false if not. (I use a boolean instead of a Model just as an example. You would use your Model instead)

Comment: All right now I understand. I updated the solution accordingly.